# No issue: Unfortunately google play services has stopped

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Did anyone got this error? 
It seems, clicking any button in my android application and at the same time Google related error message is occurred.

Google related error messages like,

“The process com.google.process.apps has stopped”
Or
“Google Play Services has stopped”.

I tried in emulator and my mobile, even tried deleting it and adding a new one, still i got the same message.

Please Advice...

Comment: try in real device

Comment: Can you post the logs for the crash please?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes up when you are making some changes to the settings of the Android Operating System. You may refer with this article on [How To Fix ‘Google Play Services Has Stopped’ Error On Android](http://www.mobipicker.com/fix-google-play-store-stopped-error-android-device/).

- emptying the cache of the system app Google Play Services.
- reset the app preferences
- add your Google Account Once Again
- reinstall Google Play Services
- clear the Google Service Framework cache

However, if none of this works, you may want to consider checking this another [blog](https://maxwell.en.softonic.com/blog/turbo-booster/how-to-fix-the-google-play-services-has-stopped-error).